# Is there a way to print custom message when there is no error

Tags: r

I know about tryCatch to customize error message. But is there a way to incorporate messages when there is no error. For example the below code does not show any error. But can we print like " No error and the code is good"

```
a <- 2+6 # we get no error here.
```

Comment: This is a strange request...maybe add a `cat('Everything is fine') ?

Comment: Thanks for your time. Sorry Did not get you. Can you come again

Comment: I was proposing adding a line in your cade that print text, like with the `cat` function.
Like `a <- 2+6 ; cat('Everything is nice')`. But you need to modify your script...

Answer (score 0):

You can add lines in your code to notify you like below :

```
a <- 2+6 
cat('Everything in fine at this line')
```